# VIsual studio debug icon meaning

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

I'm using Visual Studio 2102, working on an MVC project.

What does a CIRCLE WITH A MINUS (`-`)  inside of it mean  while debugging in visual studio

This signal icon or whatever is on the VisitedObjects property (ViewData.TemplateInfo.VisitedObjects)

According to MS page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y47ychfe.aspx, for the signal icons, I don't see anything like it.

Here's the image of the icon I have questions about:

[image]

Comment: According to [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5557y8b4.aspx#BKMK_Breakpoint_Glyphs), there isn't a debugging symbol that has a minus in it. You will have to post a screenshot (or a link to one).

Comment: @adrianbanks  Updated post with image link, thanks

Comment: I'm getting the same signal icon on a simple public class with only all public accessors (get/set) on only two of the properties.  The kicker is they're all properties, but two of them show up as variable icons.  It also won't save to Entity Framework either (but all the other properties save fine.)